# Truffle migrate vs Truffle deploy

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

Is there any difference between truffle migrate and truffle deploy, as of now what I observed is both the command perform deployment on desired networks

one recognizable difference which we can see in console is,
when we run

```
truffle deploy
```

consoles shows,

> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
>
> Deploying Migrations...

and when we run

```
truffle migrate
```

> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
>
> Replacing Migrations...

can any one explain what is the exact difference between these two and is there any effect on deployment done by these two different ways.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`truffle deploy` is an alias for `truffle migrate`. They both do the same thing.